# Sending Signalr message from hub to signal has no effect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

I have a asp.net net core application, where I want to send a message from the hub to the client (the converse is already working for me).

So I have this controller action, where I am injecting my Hub into:

```
    public IActionResult to()
    {
        _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "user", "message");
        return View("~/Views/msg/ClientReceiver.cshtml");
    }
```

So, it's basically just sending a message, and returning a view.

here's the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <button onclick="receive()">Receive msg from server</button>


    <script src="~/lib/signalr/signalr.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/ClientReceiver.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the ``ClientReceiver.js` file that is being referenced looks like so:

```
function receive() {
    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/NotificationHub")
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
        .build();


    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) => {
        alert(message);
    });
}
```

When looking at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0#call-client-methods-from-the-hub) (going to the heading "Call client methods from the hub"), then it seems like this should work.

This does'nt work though, no Alert message appears when it should.
The console in my browser indicates that the correct connection has been established though:

```
[2021-06-24T23:11:48.359Z] Information: Normalizing '/NotificationHub' to 'https://localhost:44385/NotificationHub'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter the to method to return to your `ClientReceiver.cshtml` page, your `ClientReceiver` is not connected yet, so the page cannot receive your message, you should rewrite a method, and visit the method every time you click the button and send message.

You can try to change your `ClientReceiver.js` like below:

```
function receive() {
$.ajax({
    url: '/home/send',
    type: 'get',
});
}

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/NotificationHub")
    .build();
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user,message) {
    alert(message);
});
connection.start();
```

Controller:

```
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hub;

    public HomeController( IHubContext<NotificationHub> hub)
    {
        _hub = hub;
    }

    public IActionResult To()
    {
        return View("~/Views/msg/ClientReceiver.cshtml");
    }
     public async Task SendAsync()
    {
        await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "user", "message");
    }
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: this makes really good sense. But about the `sendAsync()` function in the controller. It is'nt really clear to me that it is called every time the button is pushed? how do you achieve that?